# Visual Studio 2022 error cs0400 when I add an image to a button in toolstrip

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022

Added a second form, added toolstrip to it, added a button to it. Selected an image from the resource file in properties. The project stopped running with the following error:

"Error CS0400 The type or namespace name 'Properties' could not be found in the global namespace (perhaps missing an assembly reference?) proxysForm.Designer.cs"

```
this.toolStripButton1.Image = global::Properties.Resources.Run;
```

Comment: In solution explorer, go to your project, open the properties node, traverse to `Resources.resx` then open `Resources.Designer.cs` and note the namespace e.g. namespace `YourProjectName.Properties`. Can you find the above and if so what did you find? Note with a standard winforms project you need only use `Properties.Resources.Run` unless the resources does not exists or is a diifferent namespace.

Comment: @KarenPayne Worth it in namespace XlsExe.Properties, my project name XlsExe.

Comment: Rather than diagnosing this in the current project, create a throw-a-way project, add the same resource, try `toolStripButton1.Image = Properties.Resources.Run;` does it work?

Comment: @KarenPayne Works on a new project. And it generates this line in Form.Designer.cs -> this.toolStripButton1.Image = global::WinFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.Run; Project based NET 6 WinForms

Comment: That is what I suspected. Back in the original project for lack of a better term, something is out of place and without seeing the resource designer code have no recommendations on what to do next.